# What are the disadvantages of using presentModalViewController which is now deprecated in iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want my iphone app to run on old iOS versions too, so i am using presentModalViewController, but at the same time i'm worried about the catastrophe it may bring as i am using a deprecated method.

Thanks.

Comment: `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is iOS5 and above, so you don't have to use `presentModalViewController:animated:`

Comment: "What are the disadvantages of using presentModalViewController which is now deprecated" - answer in the question - it's **deprecated.**

Comment: thanks for the presentViewController tip. But i still want to know using deprecated methods bring what disadvantages ?

Comment: deprecated methods are not recommended to be used because they will be removed on later versions, but they still work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

H2CO3 is quite right: The reason to not use a deprecated feature is that is that Apple has given us fair warning that, being deprecated, future releases of iOS may not support it, and therefore your app might not work on future versions of iOS. The new [`presentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a) gives you all of the functionality of the deprecated method, plus gives you the option of a `completion` block. Maybe you don't need that (in which case you'd just pass `nil`), but that's no reason to use a deprecated feature.

You should only use the deprecated method if you're planning on supporting iOS prior to the version of iOS required by the new method (in this case iOS 5), and if you do, you should conditionally use the deprecated method only for those older versions (i.e. as Steve suggests, check to see if your object `respondsToSelector` for the new method, and if so use that, if not use the old version).

Comment: Probably the history of iOS is too short too know for sure. On the Mac, things go from deprecated to unavailable. However, its often the case that even though you can no longer use some feature, apps build with it years early still work (this is why some Apps I have on my Mac work after 10 years or more). For sure, at some point in the future, the API will be removed and you will not be able to build with this method. But apps build by you now may continue to run on future versions. I guess what makes iOS so different is the hardware changes often enought that so old apps won't run anyway.

Comment: @DavidH Agreed. As a practical reality, I`d be surprised if `presentModalViewController` disappeared any time soon. But the fact that it may become unavailable at some future date seems like the very definition of "deprecated." I assume you're not suggesting that people continue to use deprecated methods, as that seems antithetical to good, defensive programming techniques.

Comment: The most severe issue you get when you update Xcode is your code doesn't compile anymore. Its really unlikely it will stop working in iOS7. In ios8, yeah, I'd be worried. By iOS9 I'd be very worried :-). But my read of 'deprecated' means you can no longer compile your code - the issue of whether old binaries run or not is a completely different matter, and not one I've seen fully explained. Again, some OSX binaries from 2002 still run on my mac.

Comment: According to Apple, "a method identified as deprecated has been superseded and may become unsupported in the future." I agree that, in practice, you can get away with it for a while, but I would never suggest that people continue to use methods after they're deprecated (unless done like I outline in my answer). To continue to use deprecated methods is just not good defensive programming. In my opinion, we should do what we easily can to "future-proof" our apps. I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this one. :)

Comment: Let me propose a middle ground. The APIs will not let you use that API in release X. The release where your currently in-the-store app crashes due to the actual system interface being removed is Y. I assert that Y > X, not Y >= X. Often its Y >> X. In no case is it Y = X.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a deprecated method in order to support older versions merely check if the object responds to the new method.  If not, you're on an older version and need to use the old method.

```
if ([myVC respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
   //use the new version
} else {
   //use the old version.
}
```

Comment: +1 I agree. Using `respondsToSelector` to check for the availability of a method (and using `NSClassFromString` for weakly linked classes), is a better way to perform runtime availability of given methods and classes. I've updated my answer accordingly.